# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161 in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

none of solutions on net, didn't solve my problem.how can i correct this error?

> form.blade.php:

```
<div class="row">
@include('admin.partials.errors')
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
<form action="{{ url('file') }}" name="POST" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ csrf_field() }}

<div class="form-group">
<label for="file_title">عنوان فایل:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="file_title" id="file_title" value="{{ old('file_title', isset($fileItem)? $fileItem->file_title:'') }}">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="file_description">توضیحات فایل:</label>
<textarea name="file_description" class="form-control" id="file_description" cols="30" rows="10" value="{{ old('file_description', isset($fileItem)? $fileItem->file_description:'') }}"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="file_title">فایل:</label>
<input type="file"  name="fileItem">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">ذخیره اطلاعات</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

> create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section('content')
@include('admin.file.form')
@endsection
```

> FilesController.php

```
public function create()
{
return view('admin.file.create')->with('panel_title', 'ایجاد فایل جدید');
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
dd($request->all());
}

public function edit()
{

}
```

> web.php

```
Route::get('/file','FilesController@index')->name('admin.file.list)//admin/user
Route::get('/file/create', 'FilesController@create')->name('admin.file.create');//admin/user
Route::post('/file/store','FilesController@store')->name('admin.file.store');//admin/file
Route::get('/file/edit/{file_id}','FilesController@edit')->name('admin.file.edit');//admin/file
Route::post('/file/edit/{file_id}','FilesController@update')->name('admin.file.update');//admin/file
 });
```

when i click on save button to store file details on create file page in admin panel, i get this error!

Comment: it says there is not url like that means you didn't created url for that

Answer (score 0):

For Upload file on Laraval Public/Storage

Put this Code in Controller

> FilesController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
{ //after file store
    return redirect(url('//**Put your Own url which you want**'));
}
```

Or Give another url which present in Your Web.php

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to change this line

```
Route::post('/file/store','FilesController@store')->name('admin.file.store');//admin/file
```

to this

```
Route::post('/file','FilesController@store')->name('admin.file.store');//admin/file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<form action="{{ url('file') }}" name="POST" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

to

```
<form action="{{ url('file/store') }}" name="POST" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Try better he can redirect after file store its easy